# Stopwatch interface OOP (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented, ecmascript-6, timer

I'm learning OOP and the first exercise of the course was to made a Stopwatch class. I did it really fast and decided to make an interface for this little app.

I created the interface. Basically I want to know if the aproach that I used is fine, if I needed to create another class to control the ui, etc. I'm really lost with this OOP-UI integration thing.

The app is available in https://nacho-p5.github.io/

Here's the code:

Repo: https://github.com/nacho-p5/nacho-p5.github.io

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Online Stopwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sw">
        <span id="sw-screen">0.00</span>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button type="submit" id="btnStart" class="btn">Start</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btnStop" class="btn">Stop</button type="submit">
            <button type="submit" id="btnReset" class="btn">Reset</button type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="stopwatch.js"></script>
</html>
```

#### stopwatch.js

```
// SW class
function Stopwatch() {
    let counter = 0;
    let intervalID = 0;
    const screen = document.getElementById('sw-screen');

    const addMiliseconds = () => {
        counter += 0.01
        updateScreen();
    };
    const updateScreen = () => {
        screen.innerHTML = counter.toFixed(2);
    }

    // start()
    this.start = function() {
        if (intervalID != 0) {
            throw new Error('Stopwatch has already started.')
        }
        intervalID = setInterval(addMiliseconds, 10);
    };
    // stop()
    this.stop = function() {
        if (intervalID == 0) {
            throw new Error('Stopwatch has already stoped.')
        }
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        intervalID = 0;
    };
    // reset()
    this.reset = () => {
        if (intervalID != 0) {
            this.stop();
        };
        counter = 0;
        updateScreen();
    };
    // duration()
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'duration', {
        get: function() {
            console.log(intervalID);
            return counter
        }
    });
};

// UI class
function UI(arrayOfbuttons) {
    this.toggleClass = function(elem) {
        arrayOfbuttons.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('activeBtn'))
        elem.classList.add('activeBtn');
    };
    this.removeClass = function() {
        arrayOfbuttons.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('activeBtn'))
    };
};

// HTML components
const screen = document.getElementById('sw-screen');
const btnStart = document.getElementById('btnStart');
const btnStop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
const btnReset = document.getElementById('btnReset');

// Initialize classes
const sw = new Stopwatch();
const ui = new UI([btnStart, btnStop]);

// Add event listeners
btnStart.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sw.start();
    ui.toggleClass(this);
});
btnStop.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sw.stop();
    ui.toggleClass(this);
});
btnReset.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sw.reset();
    ui.removeClass();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Code Review! Hopefully you find the feedback here and in other posts useful!

### Good things

The code makes good use of `const` for items that shouldn't be re-assigned (e.g. `screen`, `btnStart`, `screen`, etc.) and `let` for re-assignable values (e.g. `counter`, `intervalID`).

### Suggestions

This code uses some ES6 features like arrow functions - thus it could use the [class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Until then, each instance of `StopWatch` has methods defined using `this.[method]`. This works but isn't as efficient as using [the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). Such a change might likely require changing local variables to instance variables (e.g. `screen` => `this.screen`).

The naming of methods on `UI` could be more appropriate - e.g. `toggleClass` would be more appropriate as `toggleActiveClass` because it toggles the `activeBtn` class, and `removeClass` would be more appropriate as `removeActiveClass` for the same reason.

I see that the Error is thrown when clicking the button with text *Start* twice, which makes sense, but perhaps the click event handler should only call the function `sw.start` (as well as `ui.toggleClass(this)`) if `intervalID === 0` - if that is a case then perhaps a public method to determine if the Stopwatch is started is necessary.

I noticed the HTML for the buttons labeled *Stop* and *Reset* have attributes on the close tag:

> ```
> <button type="submit" id="btnStop" class="btn">Stop</button type="submit">
> <button type="submit" id="btnReset" class="btn">Reset</button type="submit">
> ```

Setting attributes on the closing tags will either be ignored by the browser, or could lead to an error - see answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4138006/1575353) for more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From a short review;

- You cannot trust `setInterval(addMiliseconds, 10);` to actually call every 10 milliseconds, JS will only *try* to honour that and it will not try very hard, your time will always be off, which is shame for a timer ;) [See this link for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript). In essence you need to keep track when the time started and then do something like `var delta = Date.now() - start; // milliseconds elapsed since start`
- You are styling your buttons with a `btn` class, since there are no other buttons you might as well style the `button` tag itself
- I am not a big fan of putting `<script>` tags after the `<body>`, I would just put the script in the header and wait for the [DOM Content Loaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) to trigger.
- Other than that, your HTML looks great
- `screen` is an unfortunate name for the passed time field
- Only `throw` when you are planning to catch, otherwise you create a bad user experience

This is my counter proposal;

```js
// Initialize classes
const ui = new UI();
const sw = new Stopwatch();
const controller = new Controller(ui, sw);

// SW class
function Stopwatch() {
  this.counter = 0;
  this.since = 0;
  this.intervalID; //Undefined is fine to start with
  //stopwatches should not know about the DOM
  //const screen = document.getElementById('sw-screen');

  this.updateTimer = function updateTimer(){
    this.counter = (Date.now() - this.since) / 1000;
  };

  this.start = function start() {
    if (!this.intervalID) {
      this.intervalID = setInterval(controller.tick, 10);
      this.since = Date.now();
    }
  };
 
  this.stop = function stop() {
    if (this.intervalID) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalID);
      this.intervalID = 0;
    }
  };

  this.reset = function reset(){
    if (this.intervalID != 0) {
      this.stop();
      this.counter = 0;
    };
  };

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'duration', {
    get: function() {
      console.log(intervalID);
      return counter
    }
  });
};

// UI class
function UI() {
  // HTML components
  this.buttons = {
    start: document.getElementById('start'),
    stop: document.getElementById('stop'),
    reset: document.getElementById('reset')
  };
  this.display = document.getElementById('display'); 

  this.updateDisplay = function(sw){
    //If innerText works, then use that
    this.display.innerText = sw.counter.toFixed(2);
  }

  this.showButtonAsActive = function showButtonAsActive(b) {
     this.resetAllButtons();
     b.classList.add('activeBtn');
  };
  this.resetAllButtons = function resetAllButtons() {
    Object.values(this.buttons).forEach(e => e.classList.remove('activeBtn'))
  };
};

function Controller(ui, sw){
// Add event listeners
  ui.buttons.start.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sw.start();
    ui.showButtonAsActive(this);
  });
  ui.buttons.stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sw.stop();
    ui.showButtonAsActive(this);
  });
  ui.buttons.reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sw.reset();
    ui.resetAllButtons();
    ui.updateDisplay(sw);
  });
  this.tick = function timerTick(){
    sw.updateTimer();
    ui.updateDisplay(sw)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Online Stopwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sw">
        <span id="display">0.00</span>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button type="submit" id="start">Start</button>
            <button type="submit" id="stop">Stop</button>
            <button type="submit" id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Sam Onela and konijin, many thanks for your responses. They gave me cool start points to continue learning. The proposal of code from konijin was great, I learned a lot reading that.

I made the following changes. This was extracted from your comments:

- Use ES6 class syntax
- Adds methods to prototype rather than instance
- Use appropiate names in vars, attrs and methods
- Replace the error handler logic when start/stop are clicked twice
- Remove attributes in closing HTML tags - This was a typo
- Change time tracker logic. Don't count time based on setInterval iterations
- Don't put the script tag after body - Changed using defer
- Only throw when you are planning to catch
- Stopwatches should not know about the DOM - changed

Also, inspired on konijin's solution I refactored the code using the observer pattern. I had two goals doing that:

1. Implement the observer pattern
2. One class - One thing: SW class must be fully functional without a ui, UI class only changes things in DOM and controller class take the decisions

What do you think about?

#### stopwatch.js

`````
class Stopwatch {
    _timer = 0;
    isRunning = false;
    startTime = 0;
    elapsedTime = 0
    observers = []

    get timer() {
        return this._timer
    }
    
    set timer(val) {
        this._timer = val
        this.notifyController(val)
    }

    registerObserver(observer) {
        this.observers.push(observer);
    };

    notifyController(val) {
        this.observers.forEach(observer => {observer.update(val)})
    }

    updateTime() {
        const newTime = Date.now() - this.startTime + this.elapsedTime;
        this.timer = newTime;
    };

    start() {
        if (!this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.startTime = Date.now();
            this.setIntervalID = setInterval(this.updateTime.bind(this), 100);
        };
    };

    stop() {
        if (this.isRunning) {
            clearInterval(this.setIntervalID);
            this.isRunning = false;
            this.elapsedTime = this._timer;
        };
    };

    reset() {
        clearInterval(this.setIntervalID);
        this.isRunning = false
        this.elapsedTime = 0;
        this.startTime = 0;
        this.timer = 0;
    };
};

class UI {
    constructor(displayID, btnStartID, btnStopID, btnResetID) {
        // HTML Components
        this.buttons = {
            start: document.getElementById(btnStartID),
            stop: document.getElementById(btnStopID),
            reset: document.getElementById(btnResetID)
        },
        this.display = document.getElementById(displayID)
    };

    resetAllButtonsStyle() {
        Object.values(this.buttons).forEach(e => e.classList.remove('activeBtn'))
    };

    showButtonAsActive(btn) {
        this.resetAllButtonsStyle();
        btn.classList.add('activeBtn')
    };

    updateDisplay(value) {
        this.display.innerText = value;
    };
}

class Controller {
    constructor(sw, ui) {
        this.sw = sw;
        this.ui = ui;

        // Add event listeners
        this.ui.buttons.start.addEventListener('click', function() {
            sw.start();
            ui.showButtonAsActive(this);
        });
        this.ui.buttons.stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (sw.isRunning) {
                sw.stop();
                ui.showButtonAsActive(this);
            };
        });
        this.ui.buttons.reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
            sw.reset();
            ui.resetAllButtonsStyle();
        });
    }

    update(val) {
        ui.updateDisplay((val/1000).toFixed(3))
    }
}


// Initialize classes

const ui = new UI('sw-display', 'btnStart', 'btnStop', 'btnReset');
const sw = new Stopwatch();
const controller = new Controller(sw, ui);

// Register controller in sw 
sw.registerObserver(controller);

////////////////////////


````
`````

Comment: This might be better as a follow up question that links to the original question.

Comment: Also, just saying, an upvote would be nice if you liked our answers ;)

Comment: Sure konijin! I'm new to this site and don't really know how it works ;)
@pacmaninbw follow up question = new question with some kind of link to this? how i can do that? sorry for the noob questions but i'm really new to this site

Comment: This [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132876/knights-tour-improved-refactored-recursive-breadth-first-search-for) is a follow up question I asked. To create a link enter the text you want as a link, select that text and use the `link` icon in the mark down editor for the question (the link icon is 2 links in a chain). You can also just hard code the URL of the original question.

Comment: Did you create the question with [this unregistered account](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/227667/nax-p5)? if so, you can click the [Contact](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page and request the accounts be merged. Also, if you haven't already read it, please read [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks for your advices! I merged my account and created a follow up question available [in this link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247312/js-stopwatch-this-is-a-good-way-to-implement-the-observer-pattern)