# Segment road map data with heuristics

Tags: c++, c++11, computational-geometry

### Backstory

A little while ago I was assigned with the task of clustering some road segments using open street map data. After parsing a huge XML (maybe that should be another review) I ended up with the following data format:

```
struct node {
  std::string id;
  double lat;
  double lon;
  int refs;
  node();
  void print();
};

struct road{
  std::string id;
  std::string type;
  std::vector<int> nodes;
};
```

So a node has the 2 coordinates plus an id and a ref number, because later I'm supposed to keep track when a node is part of 2 different roads. A road has an id and a type and the vector has the indexes of its nodes in a `vector<node>` I'm using to keep the nodes. Also this vector doesn't change in size, so it's safe to keep indexes like that.

### Segmenting

My actual task is to make segments out of these roads according to the following criteria:

- When the curvature of the segment's circumcircle exceeds a heuristic value
- When the size of a segment exceeds a heuristic value
- When a node is also part of another road; in this case the segment ends after all the nodes that are part of other roads.

The output should be a text file with the following format:

```
segment_id, way_id, no_of_nodes, node1_lat, node_1_lon, .... lastnode_lat, lastnode_lon
```

My solution is this

```
inline double curvature(double l1, double l2, double l3){
  return l1*l2*l3/sqrt((l1+l2+l3)*(l2+l3-l1)*(l3+l1-l2)*(l1+l2-l3));
}

void write_segment(ofstream &out, int &id, string way_id, vector<double> &coords,
  int &minsize, int &maxsize, int &tot_n){
  out << id << ", " << way_id << ", " << coords.size()/2 << ", ";
  for(size_t i=0; i<coords.size()-1; i++){
    out << coords[i] << ", ";
  }
  out << coords.back() << '\n';
  //check if we have new max/min
  if(coords.size()/2 < minsize)
    minsize = coords.size()/2;
  else if(coords.size()/2 > maxsize)
    maxsize = coords.size()/2;
  //ingrement the id
  id++;
  tot_n += coords.size()/2;
  //keep last node because it's also a part of the next segment
  coords.erase(coords.begin(), coords.end()-2);
}

void make_segments(const vector<road> &roads, const vector<node> &nodes,
  const string &out_s){
  ofstream out(out_s);
  bool write{false};
  //lengths for every 3 points, total and temporary curvatures
  double l1{}, l2{}, l3{}, curb{}, curv{};
  double thrs{0.03};  //curvature threshold over which a segment breaks
  int segid{};  //serial segment id for every new segment
  //count for average curvature, tot_n -> nodes written
  int count{}, tot_n{}, totalnodes{};
  //min and max segment sizes for the statistics
  int maxsize{}, minsize{std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
  size_t nthrs{200}, minthrs{4}; //min and max threshold for segment size
  vector<double> coords; //keep all the coordinates until written to file

  cout << "Segmenting:\n";
  for(size_t i=0; i<roads.size(); i++){
    totalnodes += roads[i].nodes.size();
    coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[0]].lat);
    coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[0]].lon);
    //special case for roads with one node
    if(roads[i].nodes.size() ==1){
      out << segid << ", " << roads[i].id << ", " << 1 << ", ";
      out << coords[0] << ", " << coords[1] << '\n';
      segid++;
      tot_n++;
      coords.clear();
      continue;
    }
    //make one segment for small roads (according to minthrs)
    if(roads[i].nodes.size() <= minthrs){
      for(size_t j=1; j<roads[i].nodes.size(); j++){
        coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat);
        coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon);
      }
      write_segment(out, segid, roads[i].id, coords, minsize, maxsize, tot_n);
      continue;
    }
    //for every other road segment it according to heuristics
    for(size_t j=1; j<roads[i].nodes.size()-minthrs; j++){
      //find the 3 sides of the triangle for every 3 points
      l1 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j-1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j-1]].lon,
        nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon);
      l2 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon,
        nodes[roads[i].nodes[j+1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j+1]].lon);
      l3 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j+1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j+1]].lon,
        nodes[roads[i].nodes[j-1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j-1]].lon);
      //compute circumcircle radius (curvature)
      curb = curvature(l1,l2,l3);
      count++;
      //exclude the roads with curvature >1 from average curvature
      if(isfinite(curb) && curb <=1)
        curv += curb;

      coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat);
      coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon);
      //start checking if we need to "cut" the segment
      //if the segment is too small don't cut it no matter what
      if(coords.size()/2+1 <= minthrs){
        continue;
      }
      else if(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].refs >=2 && nodes[roads[i].nodes[j+1]].refs ==1){
        //indicate that we have to flush next
        write = true;
      }
      else if(curb>thrs || coords.size()/2+1 >= nthrs || write){
        //check for curvature or maxsize
        write_segment(out, segid, roads[i].id, coords, minsize, maxsize, tot_n);
        write = false;
      }
    }

    for(size_t j=roads[i].nodes.size()-minthrs; j<roads[i].nodes.size(); j++){
      coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat);
      coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon);
    }
    write_segment(out, segid, roads[i].id, coords, minsize, maxsize, tot_n);
    coords.clear();
  }
  cout << "Maxsize: " << maxsize << '\n';
  cout << "Minsize: " << minsize << '\n';
  cout << "Segs: " << segid << '\n';
  cout << "Nodes written: " << tot_n << '\n';
  cout << "Total nodes were: " << totalnodes << '\n';
  cout << "Average curvature: " << double(curv/count) << endl;
}
```

I'm interested in good and bad practices this code follows, readability, especially when documenting what each variable stands for and any performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prefer Clear Naming over using namespace std**

According to the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx):

> Namespaces are used to organize code into logical groups and to prevent name collisions that can occur especially when your code base includes multiple libraries.

A collision is when 2 different functions have the same name, the same argument types and a similar functionality (this is why they have the same name). Someone developing software may want to override a function such as `std::cout`, `std::cin` or they may want to override the functionality of a class such as std::vector or std::stack. Namespaces allow these constructs to be overridden.

The use of the programming statement:

```
using namespace std;
```

hides the fact that cin, cout, vector and stack are coming from the namespace std where cin, cout,
vector and stack are used in the code. This can cause confusion of where the code is actually
coming from.

As the software becomes more complex and uses more libraries this becomes a bigger problem.

For a more detailed discussion of why it is a bad idea to use `using namespace std;` see this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer) and [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

**Reduce Complexity, Follow SRP**
The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

> Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as follows:
>           `A class should have only one reason to change.`

While this is primarily targeted at classes in object oriented languages it applies to functions and subroutines well.

The `void make_segments(const std::vector<road> &roads, const std::vector<node> &nodes, const std::string &out_s)` function could be broken up into at multiple functions. The following code is a good candidate for a function to be called by `make_segments`:

```
            //for every other road segment it according to heuristics
            for (size_t j = 1; j<roads[i].nodes.size() - minthrs; j++) {
                //find the 3 sides of the triangle for every 3 points
                l1 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lon,
                    nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon);
                l2 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon,
                    nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lon);
                l3 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lon,
                    nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lon);
                //compute circumcircle radius (curvature)
                curb = curvature(l1, l2, l3);
                count++;
                //exclude the roads with curvature >1 from average curvature
                if (isfinite(curb) && curb <= 1)
                    curv += curb;

                coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat);
                coords.push_back(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon);
                //start checking if we need to "cut" the segment
                //if the segment is too small don't cut it no matter what
                if (coords.size() / 2 + 1 <= minthrs) {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].refs >= 2 && nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].refs == 1) {
                    //indicate that we have to flush next
                    write = true;
                }
                else if (curb>thrs || coords.size() / 2 + 1 >= nthrs || write) {
                    //check for curvature or maxsize
                    write_segment(out, segid, roads[i].id, coords, minsize, maxsize, tot_n);
                    write = false;
                }
            }
```

The more separate functions there are the easier it is to understand or read the code. This also makes it easier for any programmer to maintain or debug the code.

**Prefer Iterators Over Indexes for Container Classes**
The function `void write_segment(std::ofstream &out, int &id, std::string way_id, std::vector<double> &coords, int &minsize, int &maxsize, int &tot_n)` contains the following code:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i<coords.size() - 1; i++) {
        out << coords[i] << ", ";
    }
```

A more modern and less C programming language like construct would be:

```
    for (auto coord_iterator: coords) {
        out << coord_iterator << ",";
    }
```

Using iterators in this manner makes it much easier to program correctly.

**Declare Variables as Close to Use as Possible**
In the loop defined as a possible candidate for a function there are 3 variables that should be defined within the loop rather than at the top of the function. The variables l1, l2 and l3 are only assigned values and used within the loop.

```
                    //find the 3 sides of the triangle for every 3 points
                    double l1 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lon,
                        nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon);
                    double l2 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j]].lon,
                        nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lon);
                    double l3 = euclid_dist(nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j + 1]].lon,
                        nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lat, nodes[roads[i].nodes[j - 1]].lon);
                    //compute circumcircle radius (curvature)
                    curb = curvature(l1, l2, l3);
                    count++;
```

Comment: Your `for auto` loop writes an extra comma at the end, which the original code does not.

Comment: @RolandIllig true.

Comment: I thought about declaring the l1/2/3 variables inside the for loop but isn't the constant memory allocation bad for performance? Putting std:: I think it's going to be very hard for me but I read about its advantages.

Comment: @Konstantinoscs If you are using an optimizing compiler at the O3 level performance shouldn't be affected by these declarations. You actually have a nice little function there called find_the_triangle if you want it, if curb = find_the_triangle().

Comment: Can you elaborate on the optimization a bit? Are there rules of thumb about what to not care about if you put -O?

Comment: You don't need the inline function for starters, modern C++ compiler treat that as a recommendation. The general rule is not to optimize, but I don't believe in that. Read the answer on this question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123489/recursive-breadth-first-search-for-knights-tour. I just did a google on `c++ when to write optimized code` and found these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035033/optimizing-code-cpu-vs-memory https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Writing_efficient_code/Performance_improving_features